# Adding elements using browser console

Tags: javascript, browser, console

I'm trying to add an element in a webpage using the browser console.
My element is something like:

```
<a class="myclass" role="myrole" href="/url.com">
<span class="Label">Hello World</span>
</a>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: make a method to add element and call from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML = "<a class='myclass' role='myrole' href='/url.com'><span class='Label'>Hello World</span></a>";
```

You can add a dummy div or tag with some ID and use this code

HTML:

```
<div id="myid">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addElem(elem, text)
{

    var elem = document.createElement(elem),     // element to be created
        text = document.createTextNode(text);    // text node
        bd = document.body;    // get body

    elem.appendChild(text);   // elem appended with text
    bd.appendChild(elem);     // body appended with elem
    return elem;

}
```

call it as so: `addElem('p', 'text here');`

call from console and see :)

Comment: @user2132234, it can't be..try calling it how i've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

try here itself

open your console,

`var _el = '<a class="myclass" role="myrole" href="/url.com"><span class="Label">Hello World</span></a>'`;

$('.post-text').append(_el);